# MVC 4 view to create a model with a list of another model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to capture a purchase order which has a `public list<OrderItems>` in it.

My `PurchaseOrder` class looks like this:

```
public class PurchaseOrderModel
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public StatusState Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstimatedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryMethodID { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItemModel> OrderItems { get; set; } //Class name should match
}
```

My `OrderItem` class looks like this:

```
public class OrderItemModel  
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

How would I make a view that creates a form which includes both the purchaseorder (relevant fields are supplier and delivery method) and order items (relevant fields are quantity, price and productID)?

Comment: you can create a new model with the first two as class attribute

Comment: You are going to need to generate your `OrderItemViewModel` view dynamically to the UI and use an index. Lists are handled by MVC using the index i.e. `<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[0].Price" />`. The idea is you would generate a new line of controls using the `OrderItems.Count` as the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the behaviour you are looking for is creating a PO form which you can then subsequently add an arbitrary number of order items, then the only way I can think of doing this will be to dynamically generate UI controls for each order item. MVC maps a list item to a model via index. So as a simplistic example

**CreatePO.cshtml**

```
@model PurchaseOrderModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!-- PO info controls -->
    ...
    <!-- Order item info controls -->
    <div id="orderItems"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var itemCount = 0;

            $('#btnAddItem').click(function() {
                var $itemRow = $('<div id="orderItem' + itemCount + '">' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems.Index" value="' + itemCount + '" />' +
                    '<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].Quantity" />' +
                    '<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].Price" />' + 
                    '<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].ProductID" />' + 
                    '<input type="button" class="remove" id="btnRemoveItem' + itemCount + '" value="Remove" /></div>');
                $('#orderItems').append($itemRow);
                itemCount++;
            });
            $('#orderItems').on('click', '.remove', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                itemCount--;
            });
        });

    </script>

    <input type="button" id="btnAddItem" value="Add Line Item" />
}
```

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/9mxgw/16/).

Answer (score 1):

James' answer is awesome but I notice an issue when you remove an order in between orders. For example, you added 4 orders but you remove the 3rd order. When posting the form, you'll notice that the 4th order will not be posted. For non-sequential indices, you can change

```
'<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].Quantity" />'
'<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].Price" />'
'<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].ProductID" />'
```

to

```
'<input type="hidden" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems.Index" value="' + itemCount + '" />'
'<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].Quantity" />'
'<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].Price" />'
'<input type="text" name="PurchaseOrderModel.OrderItems[' + itemCount + '].ProductID" />'
```

See [Phil Haacked's Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: I actually was aware of this issue and my intention was to come back and update my answer when I had time (which was now until I seen your answer). However, I wasn't aware of the hidden `Index` field...that's cool :) +1 I will add this to my answer given it's the accepted one for any future visitors.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this, This is just example

**Model**

```
public class PurchaseOrderModel
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public StatusState Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstimatedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryMethodID { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItemModel> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItemModel  
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@mode xxx.PurchaseOrderModel
<div>
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SupplierID)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SupplierID )
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SupplierID )
</div>
<br />
<div>
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderItems[0].Quantity)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderItems[0].Quantity)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OrderItems[0].Quantity)
</div>
```

Comment: @loopin and how exactly does this solve your problem? This means you can only ever add 1 order item per PO.

Comment: your most wc. if you have any concern let me know.

Comment: James, I know. That's the next problem. :-(

Comment: @loopin You can loop trough the results in the view because it's a list.

Comment: @loopin my answer is geared towards that type of solution. Jamie the list is going to be empty is this is a *new* PO.

Comment: Hey James, I tried your solution and unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm entirely unfamiliar with javascript though, and have absolutely no idea how I could adapt your answer to work for me.

Comment: @loopin in what way does it not work? Can't really help unless I know what the problem is...What you are after doesn't work out of the box with MVC so using JS is the only way I can think of this working. FYI the example is using jQuery I have updated it to include the jQuery script if you are unsure on how to do that.

Comment: I copy paste your code into my view and when I run it, there are no input fields. When I click "add line item" nothing happens - do I need to have blank input fields in my order items div?

Comment: @loopin don't clog this thread up, please comment on my answer below. I noticed there were some typo's in my code, updated & provided a working JSFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

You can include this in your view:

```
@model SoluntionName.Models.PurchaseOrderModel
```

You cal later use these classes as:

```
@Model.OrderNumber 
@Model.SupplierID 
@Model.DeliveryMethodID
```

And:

```
@Model.OrderItems[i].Quantity
@Model.OrderItems[i].Price
```

Answer (score -1):

In your controller you construct your model and pass it to your view:

```
var model = new PurchaseOrderModel();
model.OrderItems = // fill your order items
return view(model);
```

Then in your view you'd do something like this:

```
@model Your.Namespace.PurchaseOrderModel

@using(Html.Beginform()) {
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SupplierID )
    // etc etc.
}
```

Then in your controller create a post method with your model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrderModel model) {

if (ModelState.IsValid()) {
// save your model to database or whatever.
return Redirect( ...
}
// there are validation errors: show form again:
return view(model);

}
```